# How tell Nuget to not override a specific version of jquery?

Tags: jquery, nuget, nuget-package, nugetgallery

I have a legacy project with a lot of dependencies on jquery 1.8.

If I want to upgrade to 1.9 but maintain the older version while I download the new one from nuget, can that be done?

I just want to use the new version in a new view, instead of going through my project and trying to replace jquery with the new version and seeing if I didn't break something.

There is a way that Nuget adds an extra id on the package.config and try to use it as a discriminator id?

```
<package id="jQuery" version="1.8" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="jQuery2" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Comment: Wouldn't you actually set the script tag in your code to tell which jquery version you're actually using ?

Comment: @DinoMyte yes but if you download the package, the package.config is modified by nugget and then you can't use on your code the older version, because it replace the version with the new one.